# c printf("%x"), what does it print?

Tags: c, gdb

I type this code in c: `__asm__("mov $10, %rsi"); printf("%x")`, It print `a`.
I debug it in `gdb`, found that the result store int `register esi`.
**QUESTION**: why the result is `esi`?

Comment: Good question! EDIT: ybungalobill already stole that answer!

Comment: How did you determine that the result (presumably you mean the return value of printf, which should be 2) is stored in esi ?

Comment: `__asm__("mov $10, %rsi");` edit the `esi/rsi` value, I have try some other value.

Answer (score 12):

`printf("%x")` tries to get a second argument, but it isn't there, so it just reads the memory where it should have been, finds whatever garbage is there, and prints it.

In short: it is undefined-behavior.

**EDIT:** the reason you see the same value as in the `esi` register, is because the [System V AMD64 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) (which is the spec most Unixes follow) passes the first few arguments through registers when possible. The second argument is passed through `rsi`, therefore that's where `printf` is reading from.

Comment: What it does find, it treats as an unsigned int and prints the hex code (in lower-case) for that (which is what %x does).

Comment: @ybungalobill How does it know where the address should have been? Or in  other words it reads from where?

Comment: @Armin: It's "implementation defined". Look at the source code of your library/compiler, or consult your compiler or ABI documentation.

Comment: @Armin: the arguments are pushed sequentially to the stack, so the "next one" is the one following the previous. The exact details are ABI/architecture dependent.

Comment: @ybungalobill I add a line `__asm__("mov $10, %rsi");
 printf("%x");` , got `a`.

Comment: @sumous: I do not know what answer you are expecting, yet if you want more concrete answers you should ask more concrete questions. Without seeing the exact C code *and* generated assembly code one cannot say much beyond what was already said.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Sorry, I wants to know why the result will be `esi`

Answer (score 2):

When calling `printf("%x")`, it happens, that the arguments which it needs are pushed to the stack (in reverse order) and eventually, the function is called using assembly command `call`. When providing your format string `"%x"`, `printf()` expects at least ONE argument following, so it will read the value next on the stack, which could be anything...
So this behavior is actually undefined and often the cause for exploits, because you can corrupt the stack.

Maybe a little [excourse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack) on this topic.

Comment: Isn't the return address pushed to the stack as well once the arguments are pushed in reverse order?

Comment: @SheerFish: typically (including x86 and amd64 architectures) it is the `call` instruction that does that.

Comment: I am not a 100% sure now, but I think so... It must be somewhere so ESP/RSP knows where to go next. But this is implementation and OS dependent...

Comment: @bash.d: my platform is gcc+gentoo